# Using arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write a program in javascript in which there is a list of products in an array, and they are sorted in alphabetical order. However, when I enter the code into notepad, and load it up in the website format, it just displays the code I have entered, with no formatting

```js
var products = ["Printer","Tablet","Router","Speakers","Mouse"];
Arrays.sort(products);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(products));
```

This is the code exactly as it is in notepad, and in the website bit, it is displayed as one long line of all the programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to surround your code with a script tag:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">Your_code_here</script>
```

Furthermore `System.out.println` and `Arrays.toString` are **Java** functions. It seems like you have **Java** confused with **JavaScript**. I think what you are trying to do is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Speakers", "Mouse"];
        products.sort();
        var productsString = products.join(" ");
        document.write(productsString);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you point a browser at a URL which returns JavaScript source code, then it will display the JavaScript source code (generally not as a single line those, that suggests a further error in which you are serving it to the browser with a `Content-Type: text/html` header instead of `Content-Type: application/javascript`).

If you want to execute client side JavaScript then you need to write an HTML document and import the JavaScript using [a `<script>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script).

Your code will then fail because `Arrays` and `System` will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript not like java ..to use helper functions in javascript as ..sort,filter,reserve....you can use underscore.js library